# Custom pagination (Previous / Next)

Tags: php, pagination

So I'm working on a custom pagination following code:

```
<?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
<?php $next = get_next_posts_link( 'Previous', $the_query->max_num_pages );
$previous = get_previous_posts_link( 'Next' );
if(!empty($next)) {
  $links[] = '<li class="previous">'.$next.'</li>';
}
if(!empty($previous)) {
  $links[] = '<li class="next">'.$previous.'</li>';
}
if (!empty($links)) { ?>
  <nav class="post-nav clear clearfix">
    <ul><?php
      echo implode($links); ?>
    </ul>
  </nav><?php
} ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The pagination is working as expected. However, I would like to add a class to the nav depending depending if both "Previous" and "Next" links are displayed at the same time or not.

If both links are present the output looks like this (this is what it should look like)

[image]

But if there's only one link it looks funny.

[image]

By being able to add a class to the nav I could change the CSS

Any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... pretty much just do exactly what you said. Add a class conditionally based on the number of links O.o

```
$link_container_class = '';

if (!empty($links)) { 
  if( 1 === count( $links ) ) {
    $link_container_class = 'single';
  }
  ?>
  <nav class="post-nav clear clearfix <?php echo $link_container_class; ?>">
    <ul><?php
      echo implode($links); ?>
    </ul>
 </nav><?php
} ?>
```

Comment: That's awesome! It worked right away!